# JavaScript connecting several drop down selections

Tags: javascript, dropdown

Im newbie in JavaScript, so I was wondering if I have several drop down selections, how can I display a message of all selections that are made?

E.g.: I have a drop down selection of colors, second with sizes, third with amount. 
So, I want to display a message of all the things chosen, such as: you choose "yellow", "size M", "2 pieces". Like specification of buyers choices.

I tried like this:

```
<script> 
    function dialog() {
        var color= document.getElementById ("color").value;
        var size = document.getElementById ("size").value;
        var amount= document.getElementById ("amount").value;

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="You choose" +color+ "size" +size "in an amount of" +amount+;
    }
</script>
```

But it works only if I have one drop down, not when I have more...
Thanks for help.

Comment: And when you want to show that message (event)?

Comment: You're missing a `+` after `+size`, and you have an extra one after `+amount` - does fixing these fix your problem?

Comment: Acutally yes. I really didn't look for syntax errors.. I was looking for something more complicated. Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a default value to the dropdowns, something like:

```
<select>
  <option value="unselected">Select a Size</option>
</select>
```

Then inside your dialog function, check the values you retreived from the dropdowns to see if they match something other than 'unselected':

```
if (color != 'unselected' && size != 'unselected' && amount != 'unselected') {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="You choose" +color+ "size" +size+ "in an amount of" +amount;
}
```

This way you can also isolate which field hasn't been selected yet. Example:

```
if (color == 'unselected') {
  alert('You need to select a color');
}
```

Comment: Thank yoou, this also helps alot!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working snippet example of the combined suggestions and edits from the [Rob Brander](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37255096/5076162) and [Scott Kaye](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37254945/5076162).  The gist is to have isolated code for user interface and another set of code for validation that simply checks if the answer is not the default answer.

**Update**

Per Rob's recommendation, I added an `else` condition so that the `dialog()` will clear out the text if the input of all 3 drop lists are invalid.

```js
function dialog() {
  var color = " " + document.getElementById("color").value + ", ";
  var size = " " + document.getElementById("size").value + ", ";
  var amount = " " + document.getElementById("amount").value + ".";
  var defaultVal = "unselected";
  var colorDefault = document.getElementById("color").value;
  var sizeDefault = document.getElementById("size").value;
  var amountDefault = document.getElementById("amount").value;

  if (colorDefault != defaultVal && sizeDefault != defaultVal && amountDefault != defaultVal) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You choose color" + color + "size" + size + "in an amount of" + amount;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
  }
}

document.getElementById("color").addEventListener("click", dialog);
document.getElementById("size").addEventListener("click", dialog);
document.getElementById("amount").addEventListener("click", dialog);

document.getElementById("color").addEventListener("mousedown", dialog);
document.getElementById("size").addEventListener("mousedown", dialog);
document.getElementById("amount").addEventListener("mousedown", dialog);

document.getElementById("color").addEventListener("mouseup", dialog);
document.getElementById("size").addEventListener("mouseup", dialog);
document.getElementById("amount").addEventListener("mouseup", dialog);
```

```css
div {
  width: 80%;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  background-color: #ACE;
  height: 125px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 3px;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<select id='color'>
  <option value="unselected">Color...</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="orange">Orange</option>
</select>
<select id='size'>
  <option value="unselected">Size...</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="32">32</option>
</select>
<select id='amount'>
  <option value="unselected">Amount...</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
</select>
<div id='demo'></div>
```

Comment: Nice, but you need some way to fire dialog().  Perhaps a button or an onchange event on each of the selects